# How does casting this object to a generic type work?

Tags: java, generics, casting, effective-java

My understanding is generic types are **invariant**, so if we have `B` as a subtype of `A`, then `List<B>` has no relationship with `List<A>`. So casting won't work on `List<A>` and `List<B>`.

From Effective Java Third Edition we have this snippet of code:

```
// Generic singleton factory pattern
private static UnaryOperator<Object> IDENTIFY_FN = (t) -> t;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identifyFunction() {
    return (UnaryOperator<T>) IDENTIFY_FN; //OK But how, why?
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
    UnaryOperator<String> sameString = identifyFunction();
    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(sameString.apply(s));
    }
}
```

Here I am confused. We have cast `IDENTIFY_FN`, whose type is `UnaryOperator<Object>`, to `UnaryOperator<T>`, which has another type parameter.

When type erasure happens String is a subtype of Object, but so far as I know `UnaryOperator<String>` is not a subtype of `UnaryOperator<Object>`.

Do Object and T relate somehow? And how does casting succeed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics don't exist at runtime. At runtime, **every** `UnaryOperator<T>` is a `UnaryOperator<Object>`. The cast is necessary to placate the compiler at compile-time. At runtime it's meaningless.

Comment: The question was why the cast is legal at compile-time. A direct cast like `(UnityOperator<String>) IDENTITY_FN` would **not** be legal.

Comment: @ohlec He already answered that. Generics are invariant. `UnityOperator<String> != UnityOperator<Object>`. As I said, `UnaryOperator<T>` *is* `UnaryOperator<Object>`.

Comment: @ohlec What's your point? Type bounds are compile-time checks. Casts are runtime operations. A compiler will stop you doing a cast that it knows cannot succeed (useful) but otherwise will not step in.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the asker was unsure about. The compiler complains when it knows a cast will fail, but not when it knows a cast might fail, like in this case.

Comment: Even though I upvoted your answer, I have problems explaining why the compiler does not complains about this: 
 `private static List<Object> IDENTIFY_FN = new ArrayList<Object>();

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identifyFunction() {
  return (UnaryOperator<T>) IDENTIFY_FN; 
 }`

Comment: @EugenCovaci Because `ArrayList` - or whatever concrete type is stored in that field - could theoretically implement `UnaryOperator`. Even if you change `List<Object>` to `ArrayList<Object>` on the LHS, a subclass of `ArrayList` might implement it. I believe if `ArrayList` were final then you'd finally get a compilation error.

Comment: Right, but you said this: "At runtime, every UnaryOperator<T> is a UnaryOperator<Object>" in order to explain why the compiler doesn't complain. Or I got it wrong?

Comment: It's not a contradiction, just needs further explanations, that's all.

Comment: I Understand now that `UnityOperator<String> != UnityOperator<Object>` and,  indeed `UnaryOperator<T>` is `UnaryOperator<Object>` due to type erasure that happens at runtime. so that's why casting worked fine. to conclude the casting was just for compiler satisfaction.

Answer (score 4):

This cast compiles, because it's a special case of a narrowing conversion. (According to [§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5), narrowing conversions are one of the types of conversions allowed by a cast, so most of this answer is going to focus on the rules for narrowing conversions.)

Note that while `UnaryOperator<T>` is not a subtype of `UnaryOperator<Object>` (so the cast isn't a "downcast"), it's still considered a narrowing conversion. From [§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6):

> A *narrowing reference conversion* treats expressions of a reference type `S` as expressions of a different reference type `T`, where `S` is not a subtype of `T`. [...] Unlike widening reference conversion, the types need not be directly related. However, there are restrictions that prohibit conversion between certain pairs of types when it can be statically proven that no value can be of both types.

Some of these "sideways" casts fail due to special rules, for example the following will fail:

```
List<String> a = ...;
List<Double> b = (List<String>) a;
```

Specifically, this is given by a rule in [§5.1.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.1) which states that:

> - If there exists a parameterized type `X` that is a supertype of `T`, and a parameterized type `Y` that is a supertype of `S`, such that the erasures of `X` and `Y` are the same, then `X` and `Y` are not provably distinct ([§4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)).
>
>   *Using types from the `java.util` package as an example, no narrowing reference conversion exists from `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Object>`, or vice versa, because the type arguments `String` and `Object` are provably distinct. For the same reason, no narrowing reference conversion exists from `ArrayList<String>` to `List<Object>`, or vice versa. The rejection of provably distinct types is a simple static gate to prevent "stupid" narrowing reference conversions.*

In other words, if `a` and `b` have a common supertype with the same erasure (in this case, for example, `List`), then they must be what the JLS is calling "provably distinct", given by [§4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5):

> Two parameterized types are provably distinct if either of the following is true:
>
> - They are parameterizations of distinct generic type declarations.
> - Any of their type arguments are provably distinct.

And [§4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1):

> Two type arguments are *provably distinct* if one of the following is true:
>
> - Neither argument is a type variable or wildcard, and the two arguments are not the same type.
> - One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound (from capture conversion, if necessary) of `S`; and the other type argument `T` is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither `|S| <: |T|` nor `|T| <: |S|`.
> - Each type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with upper bounds (from capture conversion, if necessary) of `S` and `T`; and neither `|S| <: |T|` nor `|T| <: |S|`.

So, given the above rules, `List<String>` and `List<Double>` *are* provably distinct (via the 1st rule from 4.5.1), because `String` and `Double` are different type arguments.

However, `UnaryOperator<T>` and `UnaryOperator<Object>` are *not* provably distinct (via the 2nd rule from 4.5.1), because:

1. One type argument is a type variable (`T`, with an upper bound of `Object`.)
2. The bound of that type variable is the same as the type argument to the other type (`Object`).

Since `UnaryOperator<T>` and `UnaryOperator<Object>` are not provably distinct, the narrowing conversion is allowed, hence the cast compiles.

---

One way to think about why the compiler permits some of these casts but not others is: in the case of the type variable, it can't prove that `T` definitely *isn't* `Object`. For example, we could have a situation like this:

```
UnaryOperator<String> aStringThing = Somewhere::doStringThing;
UnaryOperator<Double> aDoubleThing = Somewhere::doDoubleThing;

<T> UnaryOperator<T> getThing(Class<T> t) {
    if (t == String.class)
        return (UnaryOperator<T>) aStringThing;
    if (t == Double.class)
        return (UnaryOperator<T>) aDoubleThing;
    return null;
}
```

In those cases, we actually know the cast is correct as long as nobody else is doing something funny (like unchecked casting the `Class<T>` argument).

So in the general case of casting to `UnaryOperator<T>`, we might actually be doing something legitimate. In comparison, with the case of casting `List<String>` to `List<Double>`, we can say pretty authoritatively that it's always wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2) allows such cast:

> A cast from a type S to a parameterized type T is *unchecked*
>   unless at least one of the following conditions holds:
>
> - `S <: T`
> - **All of the type arguments of T are unbounded wildcards.**
> - [ ... ]

As a result, an unchecked cast causes a compile-time unchecked warning, unless suppressed by the `SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Furthermore, during the type erasure process, `identifyFunction` and `IDENTIFY_FN` compiles into:

```
private static UnaryOperator IDENTIFY_FN;

public static UnaryOperator identifyFunction() {
    return IDENTIFY_FN; // cast is removed
}
```

and the `checkcast` is added to the call site:

```
System.out.println(sameString.apply(s));
                         ^
INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/function/UnaryOperator.apply (Ljava/lang/Object)Ljava/lang/Object
CHECKCAST java/lang/String
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

`checkcast` succeeds, because the identity function returns its argument unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

The cast

```
return (UnaryOperator<T>) IDENTIFY_FN;
```

basically amounts to a cast to the raw type `UnaryOperator`, because `T` is erased at runtime and ignored for the purpose of casts at compile-time. You *can* cast a generic type to its raw type (for backwards compatibility reasons), but you should get an "unchecked" warning.

This would also work, for example:

```
UnaryOperator<String> foo = (UnaryOperator) IDENTITY_FN;
```